# Showing “ Notice: Undefined variable:” and “ Notice: Trying to get property of non-object”

Tags: errors

Showing "Undefined variable" and "Trying to get property of non-object" notice when using the following code

```
  while($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post();

$newsbox_post_img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), '', false, '' );

$list .= '<li class="news-item">
<table cellpadding="4">
    <tr>
        <td>
             <img src="'.$newsbox_post_img_src[0].'" width="100" class="img-circle" />
       </td>
       <td>'.get_the_excerpt().'</td>
    </tr>
</table>
    </li>';

endwhile;
```

Here are the errors:

[image]

---

Update from comment:

`$q` comes from

```
function newsbox_new_loading_shortcod($atts){
      extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'posts_per_page'=>'-1',
        'news_box_title'=>'Latest News',
        'post_type'=>'post',
        'category'=>''  ),$atts,'news_box'));
        $q = new WP_Query(
              array('posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,'post_type'=>array($post_type),'category_name'=>$category));
```

Comment: Where is the query for the variable '$q'?

Comment: `function newsbox_new_loading_shortcod($atts){
     extract(shortcode_atts(array(
  'posts_per_page'=>'-1',
  'news_box_title'=>'Latest News',
  'post_type'=>'post',
  'category'=>''
 ),$atts,'news_box'));
 
 $q = new WP_Query(
             array('posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,'post_type'=>array($post_type),'category_name'=>$category));`

Comment: There are any posts? Anyway, you could try with `get_the_ID()`

Comment: Use get_the_ID() or global $post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

I have rewritten your complete shortcode. I've tested the code from my original answer, and with your code combined, the output was a bit unexpected.

Major modifications

- I've removed category and replaced it with a `tax_query` (see [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)). The reason is, a `tax_query` can be used for build-in categories and for custom taxonomies, and custom taxonomies are usually used with custom post types
- Rearranged the structure of the query a bit to make it more workable and more readable. It is also better to debug

*Please Note: This shortcode needs at least PHP 5.4*

```
add_shortcode( 'news_box', 'newsbox_new_loading_shortcode' );
function newsbox_new_loading_shortcode($atts){
    ob_start();
    $a = shortcode_atts( 
        [
            'posts_per_page'    => '-1',
            'news_box_title'    => 'Latest News',
            'post_type'         => 'post',
            'taxonomy'          => '',
            'terms'             => '',
        ], 
        $atts 
    );


    if( '' == $a['taxonomy'] || '' == $a['terms'] ) {
        $args = [
            'posts_per_page'    => $a['posts_per_page'],
            'post_type'         => $a['post_type'],
        ];
    }else{
        $args = [
            'posts_per_page'    => $a['posts_per_page'],
            'post_type'         => $a['post_type'],
            'tax_query'         => [
                [
                    'taxonomy'  => $a['taxonomy'],
                    'field'     => 'slug',
                    'terms'     => $a['terms'],
                ]
            ]
        ];
    }
    $q = new WP_Query($args);

    if ( $q->have_posts() ) : 
        while($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post();   
            $newsbox_post_img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), '', false, '' ); ?>

            <li class="news-item">
                <table cellpadding="4">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <?php if( !empty($newsbox_post_img_src)) { ?>
                                <img src="<?php echo $newsbox_post_img_src[0]; ?>" width="100" class="img-circle" />
                            <?php } ?>      
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </li>

        <?php endwhile;
        $list = ob_get_clean();

        return $list;
    endif;

    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

If you need to make it compatible with PHP versions below 5.4, just change it to

```
add_shortcode( 'news_box', 'newsbox_new_loading_shortcode' );
function newsbox_new_loading_shortcode($atts){
    ob_start();
    $a = shortcode_atts( 
        array(
            'posts_per_page'    => '-1',
            'news_box_title'    => 'Latest News',
            'post_type'         => 'post',
            'taxonomy'          => '',
            'terms'             => '',
        ), 
        $atts 
    );


    if( '' == $a['taxonomy'] || '' == $a['terms'] ) {
        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page'    => $a['posts_per_page'],
            'post_type'         => $a['post_type'],
        );
    }else{
        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page'    => $a['posts_per_page'],
            'post_type'         => $a['post_type'],
            'tax_query'         => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy'  => $a['taxonomy'],
                    'field'     => 'slug',
                    'terms'     => $a['terms'],
                ),
            ),
        );
    }

    update_option('_post_type_name', $a['post_type']);

    $q = new WP_Query($args);

    if ( $q->have_posts() ) : 
        while($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post();   
            $newsbox_post_img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), '', false, '' ); ?>

            <li class="news-item">
                <table cellpadding="4">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <?php if( !empty($newsbox_post_img_src)) { ?>
                                <img src="<?php echo $newsbox_post_img_src[0]; ?>" width="100" class="img-circle" />
                            <?php } ?>      
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </li>

        <?php endwhile;
        $list = ob_get_clean();

        return $list;
    endif;

    wp_reset_postdata();
}

function newsbox_excerpt_more($more) {
    global $post;
    $post_type_name = get_option('_post_type_name');
    if( 'post' != $post_type_name ){
        $read_more_text = "TEXT FOR ALL THAT DOES NOT HAVE post POST TYPE";
    }
    else {
        $read_more_text = "Read More &raquo;";
    }
    return '...<a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">' . $read_more_text . '</a>';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'newsbox_excerpt_more');
```

You can then use your shortcode as follows

```
[news_box posts_per_page=-1 news_box_title="Latest News" post_type="event_type"  taxonomy="event_cat"  terms="testcat"]
```

or

```
[news_box posts_per_page=-1 news_box_title="Latest News" post_type="post"  taxonomy="category"  terms="testcategory"]
```

or

```
[news_box posts_per_page=-1 news_box_title="Latest News" post_type="post"]
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

You don't need to use `$post->ID` when using [`get_post_thumbnail_id`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_thumbnail_id) inside the loop. By default, the current post ID is used, thus unnecessary to specify an ID. Also, you will need to actually check if `$newsbox_post_img_src` has something to return, otherwise it will return a

> Trying to get property of non-object

error. Another thing to note, you should reset your custom loop with `wp_reset_postdata` and output from a shortcode should be `return`ed, and not `echo`'d

Your code should basically look something like this

```
while($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post();   
    $newsbox_post_img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), '', false, '' );

    $list = '<li class="news-item">';
    $list .= '<table cellpadding="4">';
    $list .= '<tr>';
    $list .= '<td>';
    if( !empty($newsbox_post_img_src)) {
        $list .= '<img src="'.$newsbox_post_img_src[0].'" width="100" class="img-circle" />';
    }       
    $list .= '</td>';
    $list .= '<td>'.get_the_excerpt().'</td>';
    $list .= '</tr>';
    $list .= '</table>';
    $list .= '</li>';
    return $list;

endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Please see my edit. Hope this is helpful

Answer (score 1):

There are couple issues I see with your code that are probably contributing to your overall problem. Try fix the issues below and see if you can move forward with it.

Syntax error:

```
// Syntax here would cause error
$q = new WP_Query(
array('posts_per_page' => 'posts_per_page,'post_type'=>array($post_type),'category_name'=>$category));
```

Fix to something like this

```
$q = new WP_Query(
array('posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page, 'post_type'=>array($post_type), 'category_name' => $category));
```

Unnecessary 4th argument:

```
// Documentation for wp_get_attachment_image_src
// http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src

// You don't need forth argument on this line
$newsbox_post_img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), '', false, '' );
```

Fix to something like this

```
$newsbox_post_img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), '', false );
```

My advice is to ensure each line of your code is valid in terms of syntax and the usage. Otherwise you will be lost in debugging process.

Comment: Thanks @Elisha Terada for you nice answer. The editor , who edit my post has made the syntax error. You can find the correct one to my comment.