# Using "excerpt_more" filter for a specific post type

Tags: plugins, shortcode, excerpt

I have used `excerpt_more` filter in a theme's functions.php and in a plugin's functions.php. Here is the code for the theme

```
  function theme_excerpt_more( $more ) {
     return '...';
  }
  add_filter('excerpt_more', 'theme_excerpt_more');
```

and here is the code for the  plugin

```
   function newsbox_excerpt_more($more) {
   global $post;
   $options = get_option('newsbox_plugin_display_options');
   if(isset($options['read_more_text'])){
      $read_more_text = $options['read_more_text'];
   }
   else{
     $read_more_text = "Read More &raquo;";
   }
   return '...<a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">' . $read_more_text . '</a>';
 }
  add_filter('excerpt_more', 'newsbox_excerpt_more');
```

But only the theme's `excerpt_more` is working. I want the plugin `excerpt_more` to work on the post that will set in the shortcode. This is the shortcode

`[news_box posts_per_page=-1 news_box_title="Latest News" post_type="latest_news" category ="Uncategorized"]`

If I don't set `post_type`, then the plugin's `excerpt_more` will work on the default post.

Any suggestions to achieve this?

Edit: Full code

```
 function newsbox_new_loading_shortcod($atts){
 extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'posts_per_page'=>'-1',
    'news_box_title'=>'Latest News',
    'post_type'=>'post',
    'category'=>''
),$atts,'news_box'));

$q = new WP_Query(
 array('posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,'post_type'=>array($post_type),'category_name'=>$category));
$list = '<div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span><b>'.$news_box_title.'</b></div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <ul class="news_list">';

                                while($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post();

                                    $newsbox_post_img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), '', false );

                                    $list .= '<li class="news-item">
                                     <table cellpadding="4">
                                        <tr>
                                           <td><img src="'.$newsbox_post_img_src[0].'" width="100" class="img-circle" /></td>
                                           <td>'.get_the_excerpt().'</td>
                                        </tr>
                                     </table>
                                  </li>';

                                endwhile;

                                wp_reset_postdata();

                            return $list . '</ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer"> </div>
            </div>';                            

 }
 add_shortcode('news_box','newsbox_new_loading_shortcod');
```

Comment: Why you need 2 functions, can't this be done with a single one? Also you have `$post` object, so you can check with `$post->post_type`.

Comment: I am developing a plugin not only for me. It is for wordpress community. Now if a user use `excerpt_more` to there plugin and also use my plugin then it will make a conflict. For that reason i need to check that. @Chittaranjan

Comment: Please post complete shortcode code

Comment: Try higher priority value in the filter like `add_filter('excerpt_more', 'newsbox_excerpt_more', 100);`

Comment: You can check here complete shortcode @PieterGoosen http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/159818/showing-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-trying-to-get-property-of-n

Comment: Problem solve 50%. But i want to set the plugin `excerpt_more` only  on that post type that will use on shortcode. @Nilambar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in my [edit to my answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/159860/31545) to your previous post, I have rewritten your complete shortcode to be a bit more useful, and I also removed the `extract()` function which is a bad function to use.

To answer this question, I had to further modify your shortcode. To avoid clash with other excerpt functions, I have removed `the_excerpt()` and have replaced it with [`wp_trim_words`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_words). This will also void the need for the excerpt more function, so you can delete that. All that functionality is now build into the shortcode

Here is the update code. Just to renote: Needs PHP 5.4+

```
add_shortcode( 'news_box', 'newsbox_new_loading_shortcode' );
function newsbox_new_loading_shortcode($atts){
    ob_start();
    $a = shortcode_atts( 
        [
            'posts_per_page'    => '-1',
            'news_box_title'    => 'Latest News',
            'news_box_more'     => '',
            'post_type'         => 'post',
            'taxonomy'          => '',
            'terms'             => '',
            'category'          => '',
        ], 
        $atts 
    );

    if( '' == $a['taxonomy'] || '' == $a['terms'] ) {
      if( '' == $a['category'] ) {

        $args = [
            'posts_per_page'    => $a['posts_per_page'],
            'post_type'         => $a['post_type'],
        ];


      }else{
        $args = [
            'posts_per_page'    => $a['posts_per_page'],
            'post_type'         => $a['post_type'],
            'category_name'     => $a['category'],

        ];
     }

    }else{
        $args = [
            'posts_per_page'    => $a['posts_per_page'],
            'post_type'         => $a['post_type'],
            'tax_query'         => [
                [
                    'taxonomy'  => $a['taxonomy'],
                    'field'     => 'slug',
                    'terms'     => $a['terms'],
                ]
            ]
        ];
    }

    //The following lines is for the excerpt more text NEW!!
    if( 'post' != $a['post_type'] && '' != $a['news_box_more'] ){
        $read_more_text = $a['news_box_more'];
    }else {
        $read_more_text = "Read More &raquo;";
    }
    // end of excerpt more text code

    $q = new WP_Query($args);

    if ( $q->have_posts() ) : 

        while($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post();   
            $newsbox_post_img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), '', false, '' ); 

            // wp_trim_words function NEW!!
            $content = get_the_content();
            $trimmed_content = wp_trim_words( $content, 55, '<a href="'. get_permalink() .'"> ...' . $read_more_text . '</a>' ); 
            // wp_trim_words function
            ?>


            <li class="news-item">
                <table cellpadding="4">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <?php if( !empty($newsbox_post_img_src)) { ?>
                                <img src="<?php echo $newsbox_post_img_src[0]; ?>" width="100" class="img-circle" />
                            <?php } ?>      
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $trimmed_content; // Replaced the_excerpt() ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </li>

        <?php endwhile;
        $list = ob_get_clean();

        return $list;
    endif;

    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

For support for PHP < 5.4, you can do the following for the shortcode function.

```
add_shortcode( 'news_box', 'newsbox_new_loading_shortcode' );
function newsbox_new_loading_shortcode($atts){
    ob_start();
    $a = shortcode_atts( 
        array(
            'posts_per_page'    => '-1',
            'news_box_title'    => 'Latest News',
            'news_box_more'     => '',
            'post_type'         => 'post',
            'taxonomy'          => '',
            'terms'             => '',
            'category'          => '',
        ), 
        $atts 
    );

    if( '' == $a['taxonomy'] || '' == $a['terms'] ) {
      if( '' == $a['category'] ) {

        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page'    => $a['posts_per_page'],
            'post_type'         => $a['post_type'],
        );


      }else{
        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page'    => $a['posts_per_page'],
            'post_type'         => $a['post_type'],
            'category_name'     => $a['category'],

        );
     }

    }else{
        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page'    => $a['posts_per_page'],
            'post_type'         => $a['post_type'],
            'tax_query'         => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy'  => $a['taxonomy'],
                    'field'     => 'slug',
                    'terms'     => $a['terms'],
                ),
            ),
        );
    }

    //The following lines is for the excerpt more text NEW!!
    if( 'post' != $a['post_type'] && '' != $a['news_box_more'] ){
        $read_more_text = $a['news_box_more'];
    }else {
        $read_more_text = "Read More &raquo;";
    }
    // end of excerpt more text code

    $q = new WP_Query($args);

    if ( $q->have_posts() ) : 

        while($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post();   
            $newsbox_post_img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), '', false, '' ); 

            // wp_trim_words function NEW!!
            $content = get_the_content();
            $trimmed_content = wp_trim_words( $content, 55, '<a href="'. get_permalink() .'"> ...' . $read_more_text . '</a>' ); 
            // wp_trim_words function
            ?>


            <li class="news-item">
                <table cellpadding="4">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <?php if( !empty($newsbox_post_img_src)) { ?>
                                <img src="<?php echo $newsbox_post_img_src[0]; ?>" width="100" class="img-circle" />
                            <?php } ?>      
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $trimmed_content; // Replaced the_excerpt() ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </li>

        <?php endwhile;
        $list = ob_get_clean();

        return $list;
    endif;

    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Just for interest sake, you have the following in your shortcode `'news_box_title' => Latest News',`, but I can see where it fits in. I have also used it in my code, but have not used it anywhere. You will have to place it where you need it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16898/discussion-on-answer-by-pieter-goosen-using-excerpt-more-filter-for-a-specific).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function newsbox_excerpt_more($more) {
    global $post;
    if ( ! ( 'post' == $post->post_type ) ) {
        return $more;
    }
    $options = get_option('newsbox_plugin_display_options');
    if(isset($options['read_more_text'])){
        $read_more_text = $options['read_more_text'];
    }
    else {
        $read_more_text = "Read More &raquo;";
    }
    return '...<a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">' . $read_more_text . '</a>';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'newsbox_excerpt_more', 100);
```

Here filter priority is set to `100`. Also inside the function `post_type` is checked. If not `post`, then it will return default. Otherwise it will return as you write in the function.

Comment: No luck. @Nilambar

Comment: Did you change `post` to `latest_news` in post type comparison?